# Role of hormones in behaviour

Tags: motivation, sexuality

I have a very basic understanding of how hormones affect  behavior. Especially for Ex: when it comes to sexuality and motivation, I learnt from some sources(friends ans interesting conversations) that things like the male sexuality is dominated by hormones which have a feeling similar to fighting and conquering. Similarly, the sex hormone of females motivates women to develop feelings similar to settling, and creating a nest for their young ones.

I was wondering if my understanding is correct, and if so, whether the sense of purpose in life, which we depend upon to make our life seem meaningful, is also related to the same hormone. I would also like to know whether the addiction to smoking, or for that matter porn is also related to human drive to find purpose in life by secreting a similar hormone and keeping us motivated. Thus, my question is to know more about the hormones and their effect on the way we feel about our life.

For people who want a one line question, What is the effect of hormones on the way we sense life?

It would be also good if someone could point me to some books or resources where I can explore this topic better and deeper

Comment: There are a lot of "popular science" kind of results, for example yourbrainonporn.com . The hormones you might want to take a look at are Dopamine, Prolactin and Oxytocin. The question of purpose of life is related to Serotonin - with overstimulation of Serotonin receptors, for example with LSD, this question or any desire to ask that question can disappear.

Comment: same question here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/13462/which-hormones-are-known-to-cause-which-psychological-effects