# Which hormones are known to cause which psychological effects?

Tags: neuroscience

This might be a very broad question, but I'm looking for gathering a list of any hormone that can cause psychological effects - especially long-term.
I would like to build a list of psychological traits that may be caused by high rates of specific hormones.

An example of such a hormone would be testosterone, which is known to increase risk-taking among other things. So regularly taking risks may be a sign of high rates of testosterone.

So **which hormones are known to cause which psychological effects?**

Comment: How do you know it's not all of them? The human body is a fragile system and anything that upsets homeostasis causes problems.